# get_post_meta fields don't show up on posts page

Tags: custom-field, homepage, id, post-meta, options

I'm new here, and to coding! I've been working hard (so, so hard...so hard) to create my website and with occasional help I've created a look and feel I like using some custom get_post_meta fields for my banner and background under header.php.

```
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
<?php do_action( 'before' ); ?>
<?php
$banner = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'banner', true);
if (is_front_page() || $banner == '') { ?>
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
<?php
} else {
?>
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner" style="background-image: url(<?=$banner?>); background-size:cover">
<?php } ?>
```

*But I'm really stumped on this problem*--none of them show up on my /blog page, which is a pretty important page; it just shows the site's general header content, same as the front page. I've researched enough to understand that this is because I have the blog page set as the posts page (with a static homepage), so it's not referencing the same header.php content as the pages are but rather the "homepage template" which is a template that indexes the posts, so my /blog page no longer has a page ID and isn't included under `<div id="page">` that is being referenced for my custom fields. So how do I get this post index template to reference the same banner code as the *pages* of my site? The solution on this page-- [Custom fields won't display on my blog page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92285/custom-fields-wont-display-on-my-blog-page) --seems right for my problem too, but I can't figure out how and where to use the  `get_option( 'page_for_posts' )` code in my own code!

Answer (score -1):

Use it like this :

```
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
<?php do_action( 'before' ); ?>
<?php
      $page_id = ( 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) ? get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) : get_the_ID );

      $banner = get_post_meta( $page_id, 'banner', true ); 

    if (is_front_page() || $banner == '') { ?>
      <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
  <?php
   } else {
   ?>
     <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner" style="background-image: url(<?=$banner?>); background-size:cover">
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. This is considered code dumping and thereby not very useful.

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem, and this worked for me:

```
$page_id = ( 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) ? get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) : $post->ID );
$banner = get_post_meta($page_id, 'banner', true);
```

Answer (score -1):

For post/blog page

```
$posts_page = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );

$banner = get_metadata('post', $posts_page, 'banner')[0];


<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner" style="background-image: url(<?=$banner?>); background-size:cover">
```