# Why does get_post_meta not work with the posts page?

Tags: metabox, post-meta

Looking for a reason why `get_post_meta()` doesn't work with `home.php`.  From my reading I understand that it's a template and not a post or page, per "[Custom fields won't display on my blog page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92285/custom-fields-wont-display-on-my-blog-page?lq=1)".  The closest page I was able to find from searching was "[get_post_meta fields don't show up on posts page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152088/get-post-meta-fields-dont-show-up-on-posts-page)" but alas the answer doesn't go into detail why.  I have coded a custom meta box, it works, for the `front_page.php` and all custom post types but not within `home.php`.  I am using a conditional `is_home()` and it works but it seems `get_the_ID()` doesn't, the code:

```
if ( is_home() ) {
    // variables 
    $check_meta     = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'checkbox', true );
    $header_meta    = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'header', true );        
    $textarea_meta  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'textarea', true );

    // condition
    if ( ( $check_meta == 'yes' ) && !empty( $textarea_meta ) && !empty( $header_meta ) ) {
        // code
    }
}
```

Why does `get_the_ID()` appear to not work with `get_post_meta()` in `home.php` located in `header.php`?

---

Edit:

Per the comments I thought I would edit this question to help someone else in the future.  I am setting the the front page and the posts page in `Settings -> Reading`.  The below worked in my conditional for `is_home()`:

```
$check_meta     = get_post_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'checkbox', true );
$header_meta    = get_post_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'header', true );        
$textarea_meta  = get_post_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'textarea', true );
```

Comment: What is your **Front page displays** setting under Settings > Reading?

Comment: Use `get_queried_object_id()` instead of `get_the_ID()` on the blog page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your posts page is a static page selected under Settings > Reading > **Front page displays**, then `get_queried_object_id()` will return the ID for that page which you can use to fetch meta data.

```
$check_meta     = get_post_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'checkbox', true );
$header_meta    = get_post_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'header', true );        
$textarea_meta  = get_post_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'textarea', true );
```

Comment: That is what was missing, I guess I should have made an answer :)

Comment: @milo this is the correct answer and it worked, edited question to reflect comments

Answer (score 3):

The home page (*this goes for the blogpage any archive page as well*) does not have a post ID as it is not a post neither a page. These are virtual pages and does not actually exist as they where not created in back end.

[`get_the_ID()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) uses [`get_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) which uses the `$post` global to return the ID of a post or a page. Inside the loop, the `$post` global will always be set to the current post being looped through through `the_post()`.

Outside the loop, in the main query, before the loop, the `$post` global will be automatically be set and hold the post object of the first post in the query. You can check this with `var_dump( $post );`. The `$post` global will be set to the last post in the query if checked after the loop has run (*because `the_post()` has changed the value*).

On single post pages and true pages, the first post (*which will always be the only post*) will be the post that was queried, so the post ID will always (*if you are not using `query_posts`, `query_posts` will break this stuffing you big time*)correspond with the correct ID of the post or page. On any archive page, the post ID returned by `get_the_ID()` will always be the first or last post in the query depending on where it is used outside the loop.

Archive pages also cannot have post meta, as they are not posts or pages and they do not have ID's.

So, in short, `get_the_ID()` will always return `false` (*if `$post` is ever to be empty*), or the ID of the first  or last post in the query outside the loop on any type of archive page

Comment: @PieterGoosen This does not cover the case where the blog page is a page selected under Settings > Reading, in which case it is a physical page and it is possible for it to have meta data.

Comment: @Milo jip, I totally forgot about that in the hurry I was. In any case, the `get_queried_object_id()` will work then as you have rightly pointed out. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `get_post_meta()` you need to have a post id. These are your options:

1. Set a post id manually
2. Run your code in the loop and `get_the_ID()` usually *loop.php*
3. Run your code in a single page or post usually *page.php* or *single.php*

Expanding answer using TwentyFifteen theme:

1. Open *index.php*
2. Locate the loop code starting with `while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();`
3. Insert your code after code in step 2, `$meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID() );`